# Java - How to split a string on plus signs?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I was trying to split an arithmetic expression (eg "1+2+10+15") on the plus signs. However, I didn't manage to write the appropriate regular expression. I thought this would work:

```
expression.split("\\+");
```

but it doesn't. Do you know the correct solution?

Comment: it works perfectly. why do you think it didn't?

Comment: If you want to split by a non-regex pattern you can use Pattern.quote("+") to generate a properly escaped string.

Comment: Note that if you want to end up with a full fledged expression evaluator, drop regular expressions and go for a parser.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It does. However `split(...)` returns an array, it does not "transform" your `String` into a `String[]`. Try this:

```
String expression = "1+2+10+1";
String[] tokens = expression.split("\\+");
```

Comment: Thanks! It really does. It's funny though because I've tried it again in an empty project and it worked. However, it throws an exception in my other project. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, don't forget to post the exception :)

Comment: Good to hear it. I bet there's something different in the other project! :)

Answer (score 7):

this way

```
expression.split("[+]");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that regular expression "[+]"

Comment: @AnilReddyYarragonda Stuff inside [ ] is a character group. Character groups accept most of the regex special characters without escaping since they are already a regex construct.