# String Tokenizer or Split function

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String "|Republic of Ireland| v/s |Northern Ireland|". This is not a fixed String. In place of "v/s" it can be any other word.
I want only "Replublic of Ireland" and "Northern Ireland" in my output.
Please tell me how to do it by using String Tokenizer or Split function.
I want this in Java language.

Comment: You can find all your answers on SO and on google in any number of languages. Since you are failing to mention your language, this question is even bad beyond 'Give me the codez'...

Comment: I would do `String parts[] = "|Republic of Ireland| v/s |Northern Ireland|".split("\\|"), first = parts[1], second = parts[3];`

Comment: Though the gross problems with the initial statement have been remedied, there is no point in reopening this just to close it as a duplicate of [Java - How to split a string on plus signs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198373/java-how-to-split-a-string-on-plus-signs) or any of the *other* versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `split` function as:

```
String str      = "|Republic of Ireland| v/s |Northern Ireland|";
String[] pieces = str.replaceAll("^\\||\\|$","").split("\\|[^\\|]+\\|");
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/G8vo4)

Comment: The problem here is it can be anything other than "v/s" . My requirement is to fetch the String in between two "|" characters.

Comment: @Vishal Jindal: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are planing on always having to parse `v/s` just use string replace to get rid of |, and then use a split on `v.s`

---

Python:

```
"|Republic of Ireland| v/s |Northern Ireland|".split("v/s")[0].replace("|", "")
```

---

Java

```
"|Republic of Ireland| v/s |Northern Ireland|".replace('|', '').split("v\s")[0];
```

As you can see its pretty much the same in all languages.

Comment: The problem here is it can be anything other than "v/s" . My requirement is to fetch the String in between two "|" characters. I want it in Java.

Comment: you can write the Java expression all on one line too to make it look the same. Does the Python example have one too many `)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have alternating items of interest in your string, split it at the pipe character and use every second item in your resulting array.

Please specify your programming language to obtain a more detailed result.

Comment: Language is Java... My requirement is to fetch the String in between two "|" characters and ignore the other parts that does't lie between two "|" characters

Comment: So you have something like like "|WantThis|DoNoWantThis|WantThis|DoNotWantThis|WantThis..."?! Split it by the pipe character (like answers above) and use every second item of resulting array.