# Split a string with java

Tags: java, regex, string, indexof

I have two types of Strings

```
command1|Destination-IP|DestinationPort
Command2|Destination-IP|DestinationPort|SourceIP|SourcePort|message
```

I tried to split the String to get the variables
I started coding like this but not sure that it's the best way

```
public String dstIp="";
    public String dstPort="";
    public String srcIp="";
    public String scrPort="";
    public String message="";
    public String command="";

int first = sentence.indexOf ("|"); 


                if (first > 0)
                {

                    int second = sentence.indexOf("|", first + 1);
                    int third = sentence.indexOf("|", second + 1);

                 command = sentence.substring(0,first);
                 dstIp=    sentence.substring(first+1,second);
                 dstPort= sentence.substring(second+1,third);
```

Shall I continue in this way? Or maybe use regular expression? 
And if the String is

```
command1|Destination-IP|DestinationPort
```

I get an error because there are no third `|`

Comment: `myStr.split("\\|");` Or `myStr.split(Pattern.quote("|"));`.

Comment: You may also use one of the [StringUtils.split](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String)) methods from apache commons, e.g. `StringUtils.split(sentence, '|')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to split your input by pipe symbol here:

```
String[] tokens = sentence.split( "[|]" ); // or sentence.split( "\\|" )
```

Then check for # of tokens by checking `tokens.length` and act accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String line = "first|second|third";
String[] splitted = line.split("\\|");
for (String part: splitted) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

**Side note**: since `"|"` character has a special meaning (basically `"|"` means OR) in the regular expression [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), one should escape it with the backslashes.

Actually it's pretty interesting to look at the results of the unescaped version `"first|second|third".split("|")`.

Regular expression `"|"` translates into english as "empty string or empty string" and matches the string at *any* position. `"first|second|third".split("|")` returns an array of length 19: `{"", "f", "i", "r", ..., "d"}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java function split(), which manages exactly what you're looking for!

Example code:

```
String test = "bla|blo|bli";
String[] result = test.split("\\|");
```

Comment: You could have also used the search-functionality: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198373/java-how-to-split-a-string-on-plus-signs

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` with `\\|` as an argument. It returns a `String[]` which will have the different parts of the |-split String.

Comment: No, `|` should be escaped.