# Invalid port number when splitting a string - Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have a program and a word server that need to communicate between each other. I am able to do this fine, sending information to the server and receiving it again. 
I have the following code:

```
try{
     Socket sock=new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null), 12837);
     InputStream s=sock.getInputStream();
     PrintStream out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
     BufferedReader r= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
     String line = r.readLine();
     String[] code = line.split("+");
     while (line != null) {
     System.out.println ("received: " + line);

     // System.out is to the console.
     // out.println is to the server
     out.println("161*");
     line = r.readLine();
     }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     System.out.println("Unknown host. Check the hostname or ip address of the server");
} catch (ConnectException e) {
     System.out.println("Problems connecting to server. Is it running?");
} catch ( NumberFormatException e) {
     System.out.println("Port number should be an integer");
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e) {
     System.out.println("The port number needs to be less than 65536");
} catch ( Throwable ex){System.out.println ("Exception: " + ex.toString());
     }
```

The idea is that I launch the word server, run my application, it will then receive the message `"<bonjour+[code]>"` where `<code>` is a 6 random letters and numbers. What I need to is echo back to the server my user ID which is `161*<code>`.

For example the server says `"<bonjour+wj1234>"` and I need to echo back `"161*wj1234"`.

I figured the easiest way would be to split the line from the server at the `+` (I will also need to remove the `>`) but I get the following error when running it:

> The port number needs to be less than 65536

It does this even if I am not doing anything with the split string. The act of splitting the string itself is for some reason changing the port number, which I set manually to `12837` and don't change.

Comment: You are catching an ``IllegalArgumentException`` and then printing the error message about the port number. Check where that ``IllegalArgumentException`` comes from. Try placing ``e.printStackTrace()`` before the ``System.out.println``.

Comment: Somewhere in the code IlegalArgumentException is getting thrown, your catch prints that part about the port, but it was never really changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198373/java-how-to-split-a-string-on-plus-signs

Answer (score 1):

The `IllegalArgumentException` is being caused by this line:

```
String[] code = line.split("+");
```

which specifies an illegal regex, because `+` is a special symbol (a "one or more" quantifier).

You must escape the `+` symbol with a backslash to specify a *literal* plus sign:

```
String[] code = line.split("\\+");
```

Note that a backslash in a java String literal is coded as *two* backslashes (it itself is escaped).